# Аметхан Султан - дважды Герой СССР. Так как же писать его имя?

Tags: дефис

Аметхан Султан - дважды Герой СССР. Так как же писать его имя? С дефисом или слитно?

Comment: В википедии приведено мнение историка Симонова (имя-отчество-фамилия): "Амет Султанович Амет-хан". Менее формально: Амет-ха́н Султа́н.

Answer (score 1):

Статья о нем в Википедии: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD,_%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD

Имя: Султан (но по мению историка А. Симонова — Амет), фамилия: Амет-ха́н (во многих местах Амет-Ха́н).

> При рождении получил имя Амет в честь деда. По утверждению историка А. Симонова, правильное написание имени и отчества Героя должно быть таким: Амет Султанович Амет-хан. При поступлении в лётное училище данные на курсанта были записаны по крымскотатарскому обычаю — в начале собственное имя, а затем имя отца. В результате возникла путаница, и имя отца стали считать именем Героя. В итоге сыновья Амет-хана Султана по паспортам значатся, как Арслан Султанович Амет-хан и Станислав Султанович Амет-хан (хотя правильно должно быть Арслан Аметович Амет-хан и Станислав Аметович Амет-хан)[5]. Амет часто шутил над созвучностью своего имени: «Я сам и хан и султан!»[6]

А вот фотография на всю стену в музее Амет-хана в Алупке. Надпись:
**Амет-Хан Султан (1920 — 1971)**. Так что единства нет.

https://static.tonkosti.ru/images/f/fc/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BB_%D0%9C%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%A5%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B2_%D0%90%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B5..jpg

[Орфографический словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lv=x&word=%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BD):

> хан, -а; после собственных имен пишется через дефис, напр.: Мирза-хан, Даян-хан, но: Чингисхан